# How can jvm check arguments and return type when using jni invoking? How to implement this type checking?

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, dynamic-library

JNI specification require the function must be placed in extern "C" block. But C linkage doesn't contain a type descriptor. So when you invoke a native method in java code, how can jvm check if the argument number/order/type and return type of the native code in the linkage and the java native definition is compatible?

And also, I want to figure out a way to implement a type checking like this. I already know that I can use `dlopen()/dlsym()/dlclose()` on Linux Platform, but it cannot acquire the type descriptor, and because of that, I cannot proceed the type checking. Is there any other way to load dynamic library and symbols with type descriptors?

I'm going to implement this library loading and type checking in a "wheel" project we made called JustVM, repo's here:
https://github.com/lfkdsk/JustVM

Comment: At run-time, the number/type/name of the parameters (and the return value) is simply not known, so they cannot be "checked". (Here we are talking about native functions that are translated into machine code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM does not enforce type safety of native methods. It only cares about the name.

E.g. the following code will compile fine, and the library will be successfully loaded. However, when you call `nativeMethod`, JVM will crash, because it will treat return value -1 as an Object.

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.loadLibrary("test");
        new Test().nativeMethod(0, 1);
    }

    private native Object nativeMethod(long a, int b);
}
```

**test.c**

```
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Test_nativeMethod(JNIEnv* env, jobject self) {
    return -1;
}
```

If you want to retain information about argument types for dynamic linking, you'll have to encode it somehow in the function name. See [Name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Answer (score -1):

> JNI specification require the function must be placed in extern "C" block. But C linkage doesn't contain a type descriptor.

But the function name generated by `javah` does.

> So when you invoke a native method in java code, how can jvm check if the argument number/order/type and return type of the native code in the linkage and the java native definition is compatible?

Because that's what it looks for, by regenerating the name based on the required arguments etc., and throws a `LinkageError` if it can't find it.

> And also, I want to figure out a way to implement a type checking like this.

So do it the same way.

Comment: JNI function name generated by `javah` from OpenJDK and Oracle JDK does not depend on method arguments and return type unless the native method is overloaded. The symbol name constructed by JVM for native method lookup does not depend on arguments or return type either.

Comment: @apangin Yes, I also confirmed that by disassembling a so-library that was build by ndk-build.
But I still don't know how JVM check the argument types and return type of the symbol to make sure there is a native function required by the bytecode loaded in VM, if neither the symbol name itself nor the C Linkage contains those information about type.